# I keep getting this error while scaffolding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

This is the full error message:

> Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file
> or assembly 'dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator-design, Version=7.0.6.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.

Every time I try to create a scaffold identity for my project, I keep getting the above error even after installing the required extensions. This are the extensions I'm using:

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="7.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers" Version="3.3.4">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="7.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="7.0.5">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="7.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Utils" Version="7.0.6" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

I have installed the required NuGet packages for code generation but I'm not able to fully grasp what the issue is. I've also tried downgrading the extensions to match the version of .NET I am using for the project and also refreshing a reloading the project a couple of times.

Answer (score 0):

Version miss match usually causes error.
You should consider use same versions of sql server, entity framework, tools and so on. Downgrade from `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design 7.0.6` to `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design 7.0.5` since there's not yet version 7.0.6 of SQL Server (as of 09th June 2023)

here is is your dependancies as I have updated them

```
   <ItemGroup>
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.5" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="7.0.5" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers" Version="3.3.4">
   <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
   <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
   </PackageReference>
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.5" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="7.0.5" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="7.0.5">
   <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
   <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
   </PackageReference>
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="7.0.5" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Utils" Version="7.0.5" />
   </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: I found another work around but I will do that and try again. Thank you